# enable program for all users (root included) installed via Terminal from source (tarball)

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, root

I can to enable some program installed from tarball...

using this command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/SomeProgram/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export MANPATH=/usr/local/SomeProgram/man:$MANPATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But how to do it for all users (including root profile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ more /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
$

$ more /etc/manpaths
/usr/share/man
/usr/local/share/man
$
```

Try with this like Root:

```
# echo '/usr/local/SomeProgram/bin' >> /etc/paths
# echo '/usr/local/SomeProgram/man' >> /etc/manpaths
```